# Loved one's or ones'

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

Can someone explain to me which would the correct form of *ones* in this statement:

> Have family members stated it took too long to respond to their loved
>   **one's/ones'** complaints?

I know it would normally be *one's* but because of the "their" before "loved" I just was unsure if that would make it multiple loved ones which therefore would be *ones'*. It just does not look correct though. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Try changing _loved one(s)_ for a different word, like _child(ren)_, and you’ll see that _their_ does not affect this at all. “Their child’s complaints” and “their children’s complaints” are both equally correct, depending on whether ‘they’ have one or more several mithering kids, just like both “His child’s complaints” and “His children’s complaints” are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how many loved ones there are.  If just one then

**one's**,

if more than one then

**ones**'

Although the latter does look odd to my eyes too, I often find words, if you stare at them too long, look (and sound), odd!

(*Their* does not influence this part of the sentence)

Answer (score 0):

As a general phrase "loved ones" is plural and not singular (usually no one refers to their "loved one").  The ownership is therefore also plural.

> He completely ignored his loved ones' complaints about his intended bride.

You are somewhat mistaken about your assumption regarding the use of "their" in the sentence.  This pronoun refers to the "family members", and is independent of the "ones".

> The soldiers were thankful to receive pictures of their loved ones.
>   The soldiers were thankful to receive their loved ones' pictures.

Comment: Certainly people refer to their _loved one_ in the singular. Not as commonly as in the plural, but not uncommonly either.

Comment: The reason "loved ones" is normally plural is because the people in question are unknown in form or quantity.  "Loved ones" is a generic way of referring to any and all people of significant importance to an individual or group.

Comment: But since we do not know what the context of the quote is, we cannot tell whether that is appropriate here. The context may make it clear that there are always just two people involved here (e.g., “loved one” could be a synonym for ‘spouse’, in which case the singular makes more sense).

Comment: Except the sentence's subject is a plural "family members" which would not have a single "loved one".

Comment: You can have plural owners of singular ownees in English; it’s just not as common. It’s more common in certain contexts than in others, though; for example, “They all touched their left ear with their right index finger” would be more common than “They all touched their left ears with their right index fingers” (which might imply that they all had several left ears and right fingers each), and there is little discernible difference between “They all took their spouse by the hand” and “They all took their spouses by the hand”, similar to this example here. Individuality vs. group affiliation.

Comment: I don't see why not. Replace (singular) _loved one_ with its synonym _spouse_, and it becomes clear that the question asks if several individual family members have stated that it took too long to respond to their individual spouse’s complaints. That is both conversationally, prosaically, and pragmatically possible and conceivable. It is still much less _likely_ than the plural, yes; but by no means impossible.